# Unable to customize AWS SES email template

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ses

I am trying to send a forgot password mail through AWS SES service. I made this template

```
{
    "Template":{
        "TemplateName": "forgotpasswrd",
        "SubjectPart": "Forgot password ",
        "TextPart":"Text area",
        "HtmlPart":"<p>We heard that you lost your password. Sorry about that!<\/p>\r\n    <p>But don\u2019t worry! You can use the following link to reset your password:<\/p>\r\n    <a href=${url}>${url}<\/a>\r\n    <p>If you don\u2019t use this link within 1 hour, it will expire.<\/p>\r\n "
    }

}
```

And this is my code in nodejs to input password reset link.

```
const params = {};
    const destination = {
      ToAddresses: [String(email)],
    };
    const templateData = {};
    templateData.url = String(Url);

    params.Source = 'myemailid@gmail.com';
    params.Destination = destination;
    params.Template = 'forgotpassword';
    params.TemplateData = JSON.stringify(templateData);
```

In this `Url` is what i am trying to send.

However when I receive the mail its it does not show the link but only the html text

" But don’t worry! You can use the following link to reset your password:

${url}
If you don’t use this link within 1 hour, it will expire."

How do I send the link in the mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `{{url}}`, not `${url}`. [See the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-personalized-email-api.html#send-personalized-email-create-template).